# Integrating MQTT with GCP using IOT adapter and google pub/sub api in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mqtt, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iot

### Integration with Cloud Pub/Sub APIs from App Engine Standard

I am working on developing a Google app engine app in standard Python environment. For some portions of the code, I need to integrate with Google Cloud pub/sub APIs.

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries), Pub/Sub can only be integrated in the App Engine flexible environment (BTW it is also only in alpha). Can someone please describe how to integrate with Pub/Sub in the App Engine Standard environment?

### My use case description

I am trying to integrate MQTT with google app engine by using Agosto IOT broker. I will be using MQTT for clients (Currently mobile platforms) and on server side, I plan to use pub/sub for receiving/sending the messages and saving relevant data to the database.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try instead to use the new [Google Cloud IoT Core](https://cloud.google.com/iot-core) product (full disclosure, I worked on it) instead of hosting MQTT on App Engine.  Cloud IoT Core lets you connect to a Google-provided MQTT bridge that will put your data into Google Cloud PubSub. You can use Google Cloud DataFlow to move your data from PubSub to your data warehouse for analytics or can use your own database as the output from DataFlow.

The connection details for communicating with the Google Cloud IoT Core MQTT bridge are [discussed in detail in the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge) but the important connection properties you will need to be aware of are the hostname (mqtt.googleapis.com) port (8883 or 443) and the MQTT password / client ID which are going to be based on the devices you've provisioned for the service.

Your actual MQTT client will need to be chosen depending on which programming language you're trying to access the MQTT bridge. If you're trying from Android, you could start from the [Java MQTT client sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/iot/api-client/manager/src/main/java/com/example/cloud/iot/examples/MqttExample.java) and would probably end up with something [like the Android Things Cloud IoT sensor hub connector](https://github.com/androidthings/sensorhub-cloud-iot/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/sensorhub/cloud/cloudiot/MQTTPublisher.java) from the AndroidThings team.

Comment: Just an FYI the `org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2` in your example needs to be updated to either use the latest version or exclude the v4 support library. otherwise you get gradle build errors. took me a while to figure out that was the issue. This is only a problem if the project you are using also uses the latest version of the support library

Comment: @class I am also looking for a way to republish messages coming to a MQTT topic to Google PubSub. The problem with not going with Cloud IoT Core's MQTT bridge is the certificate based authentication. The devices which are going to be publishing MQTT messages are not capable of doing certificate bases authentication.

Is there a way to by-pass the certificate based auth?
Is there another pattern / approach I can use to republish MQTT messages to Cloud PubSub?

I would really appreciate any help / suggestion on this regards.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - App Engine standard does not support the newer [Google Cloud Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_cloud_client_libraries). You will instead need to use the older [Google Cloud API Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_api_client_libraries) to communicate with [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/).

### Cloud API Client libraries (older) vs Google Cloud Client libraries (newer)

The [Cloud Pub/Sub client library documentation you're pointing to](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) advises you to use the older [Google API Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_api_client_libraries) (which is supported on App Engine Standard environment) instead of [Google Cloud Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained#google_cloud_client_libraries) (which is supported on App Engine Flexible environment but not on standard)

The client libraries are explained in detail [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained).

### Google API Client libraries for Cloud Pub/Sub

Here are all the [list of APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/) which are supported using Google API Client libraries. [Cloud Pub/Sub APIs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/pubsub/v1) are also part of this list.

### Using Google API Client libraries with App Engine Standard

If you scroll down that page, there is a section describing [how this API library can be used in App Engine Standard environment](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/pubsub/v1#appengine). In short, you will need to bundle the library along with your application just like other third-party libraries you use.

> ### App Engine
>
> Because the Python client libraries are not installed in the [App
>   Engine Python runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/), they must be [vendored into your
>   application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) just like third-party libraries.

This warning that you will see [on the page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/pubsub/v1), advises you to use the regular Cloud Client library if possible. But since App Engine Standard does not support it, you can ignore it for that use case.

> While this library is still supported, we suggest trying the newer
>   Cloud Client Library for Google Cloud Pub/Sub, especially for new
>   projects. See [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries) for installation and
>   usage details.

### Examples using google-api-python-client library to invoke PubSub APIs

#### Using credentials from a service account json file

The following example shows you how you can use a service account to authenticate with Google Cloud PubSub APIs and invoke them. The information about how to use credentials from a Service account is [available here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

You will need to have the following python packages pre-installed for this example to work: [`google-api-python-client`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-api-python-client) and [`oauth2client`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oauth2client).

If you're using `pip`, you can do:

```
pip install google-api-python-client oauth2client
```

**Example which I have tested personally:**

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# BEGIN CONFIG
PRIVATE_KEY_JSON = 'path/to/service_account_private_key.json'
API_SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub']
PROJECT_NAME = 'FILL_IN_PROJECT_NAME_HERE'
# END CONFIG

# The format of project name expected by PubSub
PROJECT = 'projects/{0}'.format(PROJECT_NAME)

# Create a ServiceAccountCredentials object by reading the credentials from
# your JSON file.
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    PRIVATE_KEY_JSON, scopes=API_SCOPES)

# Build the Cloud PubSub API object which you will be using for
# invoking the corresponding APIs using the credentials object
# you created previously
pubsub = discovery.build('pubsub', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# List all topics the specified project
topics = pubsub.projects().topics().list(
    project=PROJECT).execute()
print topics

# Add a new topic
topic_name = 'TOPIC_NAME_TO_ADD'
added_topic_response = pubsub.projects().topics().create(
    name='{0}/topics/{1}'.format(PROJECT, topic_name), body={}).execute()
print added_topic_response
```

#### Using credentials from a service account within an App Engine app

There is some info [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#service-accounts) regarding how to use Service account credentials from your App Engine apps.

The above example will work for the most part for invoking PubSub APIs, except for the part where you will initialize the credentials object. That part can be replaced roughly as described below:

> [**Service Accounts**](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine#service-accounts)
>
> If your App Engine application needs to call an API to access data
>   owned by the application's project, you can simplify OAuth 2.0 by
>   using [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). These server-to-server interactions do
>   not involve a user, and only your application needs to authenticate
>   itself. Use the [AppAssertionCredentials](https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.contrib.appengine.html#oauth2client.contrib.appengine.AppAssertionCredentials) class to create a
>   Credentials object without using a Flow object.
>
> In the following code snippet, a Credentials object is created and an
>   Http object is authorized:
>
> ```
> import httplib2
> from google.appengine.api import memcache
> from oauth2client.contrib.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
> ...
> credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write')
> http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http(memcache))
>
> pubsub = discovery.build('pubsub', 'v1', http=http)
> ...
> ```
>
> Once you have an authorized Http object, you can pass it to the
>   [build()](https://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build) or [execute()](http://execute()) functions as you normally would.

#### Using Application Default Credentials

You can also utilize [Application Default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) for your local testing and also works within App Engine environment.

```
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

...

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
pubsub = discovery.build('pubsub', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

...
```

Comment: Can you provide with the sample codes in python guiding how can we use Pub/Sub API client library in standard environment. I cant find any

Comment: @nisha - The API documentation I pointed to earlier has links covering the APIs - https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/python/latest/ There are some general samples here on how to call Google APIs from Python using such client API libraries - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/

Comment: I have gone through these links. But I didn't found relevant functions for performing publish and subscribe from google Pub/Sub.

Comment: @nisha - They are present under `projects()` in the above doc. [`projects.subscriptions()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/python/latest/pubsub_v1.projects.subscriptions.html) [`projects.topics()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/python/latest/pubsub_v1.projects.topics.html)

Comment: More specifically, you can look at [`projects.subscriptions().create()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/python/latest/pubsub_v1.projects.subscriptions.html#create) [`projects.topics().publish()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/pubsub/v1/python/latest/pubsub_v1.projects.topics.html#publish)

Comment: I have installed the google-api-client libraries. But when I import this library in my application, I am not able to call the function like publish() and others. They are not present in any of the files of the library but are mentioned in the docs you previously mentioned.

Comment: @nisha - Check out the example I've added to my answer. It should give you a high level overview of how to use the `google-api-python-client` to invoke Cloud PubSub APIs (same works for invoking other Google Cloud APIs as well).

Comment: @nisha - Also added snippets and pointers regarding how to initialize credentials object using Service accounts for your App Engine apps.

Comment: thanks for the earlier suggestions. All of them worked but the current issue is that I am able to run the publish command but I am not receiving the message on the Mqtt client side. But if I try with the console with the same topic, the message is  received. My command was -          
response = pubsub.projects().topics().publish(topic='{0}/topics/{1}'.format(PROJECT, "to-gateway"), body={ "messages" :[{  "attributes" : {"a_key" : "gateway-command/foo3",}, "data" : "HIII",},], }).execute()

Comment: Can you elobrate the attributes which are to be used in publish() command.

Comment: @nisha - You need to ask that as a separate question on StackOverflow. Also MQTT is just a general protocol. You have not mentioned any details about your client or your environment. Since there are so many variables, it is not possible to debug this without further detailed steps of what you tried. I would recommend posting that as a separate question.